# Returning multiple values from PL/SQL function within IF statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi – I’m trying to get my function to return all (8) values in the select statement. Tried a couple of variations based on what I’ve found on SO but can only get it to return a single value rather than all 8. New to PL/SQL and first post on SO -  I have the equivalent running in MSSQL but quite different in PL/SQL. Any help appreciated

**### Attempt 1 – Returns the first value only**

```
create or replace FUNCTION "SP_SETGRIPSTAGE" (gripNoIn NUMBER, docNoIn NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2

IS

    PW_GRIP NUMBER := gripNoIn;
    PW_DOCID NUMBER := docNoIn;
    resultOut VARCHAR2(1);

    CURSOR c1

IS
    SELECT pw_code FROM ENV_LKP_GRIP ORDER BY pw_code;

BEGIN

IF PW_DOCID > 0 THEN
    RETURN PW_GRIP;
ELSE
    OPEN c1;
    FETCH c1 into resultOut;
END IF;

    CLOSE c1;
    RETURN resultOut;

END SP_SETGRIPSTAGE;
```

**### Attempt 2 – Returns the last value only**

```
create or replace FUNCTION "SP_SETGRIPSTAGE" (gripNoIn NUMBER, docNoIn NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2

IS

    PW_GRIP NUMBER := gripNoIn;
    PW_DOCID NUMBER := docNoIn;
    resultOut VARCHAR2(1);

    CURSOR c1

IS
    SELECT pw_code FROM ENV_LKP_GRIP ORDER BY pw_code;

BEGIN

IF PW_DOCID > 0 THEN
    RETURN PW_GRIP;
ELSE
    OPEN c1;
    LOOP
    FETCH c1 into resultOut;
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN resultOut;
END IF;

    CLOSE c1;

END SP_SETGRIPSTAGE;
```

Comment: How do you want the caller to see them - as a ref cursor? A collection?

Comment: It's important to understand that there are major conceptual differences between TSQL (the language used with Microsoft SQL Server) and PL/SQL (the language used with Oracle). Most importantly in this case - in TSQL functions can return what appears to the caller to be a  "table". This is not the case in PL/SQL. A PL/SQL function can return an opened **cursor**, but it's then up to the caller to iterate through the cursor to obtain the rows. Best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

Return a cursor:

```
create or replace FUNCTION SP_SETGRIPSTAGE (
  gripNoIn NUMBER,
  docNoIn NUMBER
) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
   resultOut SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  IF docNoIn > 0 THEN
    OPEN resultOut FOR
    SELECT   pw_code
    FROM     ENV_LKP_GRIP
    ORDER BY pw_code;
  ELSE
    OPEN resultOut FOR
    SELECT   gripNoIn AS pw_code
    FROM     DUAL;
  END IF;

  RETURN resultOut;
END SP_SETGRIPSTAGE;
/
```

or a collection:

```
create or replace FUNCTION SP_SETGRIPSTAGE (
  gripNoIn NUMBER,
  docNoIn NUMBER
) RETURN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
IS
   resultOut SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
  IF docNoIn > 0 THEN
    SELECT   pw_code
    BULK COLLECT INTO resultOut
    FROM     ENV_LKP_GRIP
    ORDER BY pw_code;
  ELSE
    resultOut := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST( gripNoIn );
  END IF;

  RETURN resultOut;
END SP_SETGRIPSTAGE;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for both answers. I think it’s a collection I need but it won’t quite compile (PLS-00382 expression is of wrong type) however it’s closer than I had.

Below is effectively what I’m try to do. Issues seems to be in just returning the initial parsed value


/
If docNoIn > 0
    Return the initial parsed gripNoIn value (single value)
Else
    SELECT   pw_code FROM     ENV_LKP_GRIP ORDER BY pw_code; (multiple values)
End if
/

Comment: @DavidPerrie - both of these compile and run OK, and do what you asked for. Are you getting a compilation error, or a runtime error when you call the function? If the latter how are you calling it?

Comment: @Alex Poole

Cursor: compiles/runs but nothing appears in my dropdown when plugged into my application

Collection: compiles but doesn’t run with the below messages

Connecting to the database pwise_nrip.
ORA-06550: line 16, column 16:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 16, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database pwise_nrip.